# Best way to unit test ASP.NET MVC action methods that use BindingHelperExtensions.UpdateFrom?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

In handling a form post I have something like

```
    public ActionResult Insert()
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        BindingHelperExtensions.UpdateFrom(order, this.Request.Form);

        this.orderService.Save(order);

        return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = order.ID });
    }
```

I am not using explicit parameters in the method as I anticipate having to adapt to variable number of fields etc. and a method with 20+ parameters is not appealing.

I suppose my only option here is mock up the whole HttpRequest, equivalent to what Rob Conery has done. Is this a best practice? Hard to tell with a framework which is so new.

I've also seen solutions involving using an ActionFilter so that you can transform the above method signature to something like

```
[SomeFilter]
public Insert(Contact contact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using [ModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709/how-do-you-use-the-new-modelbinder-classes-in-aspnet-mvc-preview-5#34725) so that my action method can look (basically) like:

```
    public ActionResult Insert(Contact contact)
    {

        if (this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.contactService.SaveContact(contact);

            return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = contact.ID });
        }
        else
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an interface and mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Use NameValueDeserializer from http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib instead of UpdateFrom.